# DRF-simple-JWT: New user registered but not able to login

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am able to create a New User using the "register" endpoint. I can the user being created on the admin page as well. When I try to get an access token for the newly created user I get the error `"detail": "No active account found with the given credentials"`. I am correctly passing the valid credentials so I don't know what the problem might be. [Here I have demonstrated the same.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YxjNfIm3P4fgfHEKH4qMWs2HKB1wY652/view?usp=sharing)
Here goes the code:

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

class RegisterUserSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def validate_password(self, value: str) -> str:
        """
        Hash value passed by user.

        :param value: password of a user
        :return: a hashed version of the password
        """
        return make_password(value)
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from .serializers import RegisterUserSerializers
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken


class CustomUserCreate(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request):
        reg_serial = RegisterUserSerializers(data=request.data)
        if reg_serial.is_valid():
            newUser = reg_serial.save()
            if newUser:
                context = {
                    "message": f"User created {newUser}"
                }
                return Response(context, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(reg_serial.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class BlacklistTokenView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            refresh_token = request.data["refresh_token"]
            token = RefreshToken(refresh_token)
            token.blacklist()
        except Exception as e:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **other_fields):

        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')

        return self.create_user(email, password, **other_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, password, **other_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('You must provide an email address'))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    # REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user_name', 'first_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CustomUser model you are the is_active field is defined with default=False, you can change it to default=True or set the user to active during the registration process.

Comment: check the video I have attached. This doesn't seem to be the reason